Problem with Jenkins Pipeline and executing a stored procedure via powershell / Invoke-Sqlcmd
I'm kind of lost. My jenkins pipeline is calling a stored procedure via powershell and Invoke-Sqlcmd.
When my stored procedure runs on error, the pipeline succeeds.
Groovy looks like this.
stage('Call procedure') {
            steps {
                script{
                    try{
                        powershell("""
                        Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance "server123" -Database "yxz" -AbortOnError -QueryTimeout 0 -Query "EXECUTE usp_procedure"
                        """)
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        catchError("Error", buildResult: 'FAILURE')
                        }   
                    }
                }
            }

Any help is appreciated.
Best Regards

Add -ErrorAction Stop to the Invoke-SqlCmd call

Hi @MathiasR.Jessen, thank you very much. That did the trick.
